# How to insert a new line by using mapOf() for JSON file in Kotlin?

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I am planning to create the following JSON file in Kotlin:

```
{"Basket A": {"Row 1":"Apple", "Row 2":"Orange", "Row 3":"Pear", "Row 4":"Grapes"}}
{"Basket B": {"Row 1":"Mango", "Row 2":"Pineapple", "Row 3":"Kiwi", "Row 4":"Cherry"}}
{"Basket C": {"Row 1":"Banana", "Row 2":"Papaya", "Row 3":"Watermelon", "Row 4":"Strawberry"}}
{"Basket D": {"Row 1":"Avocado", "Row 2":"Peach", "Row 3":"Lemon", "Row 4":"Guava"}}
```

Currently I am using the following code:

```
val rows = mapOf(
"Row 1" to "Apple",
"Row 2":"Orange",
"Row 3":"Pear",
"Row 4":"Grapes"
)

val basketA = mapOf(
"Basket A" to rows
)
```

Then I can convert it to JSON by using Gson() function as follows:

```
val gson = Gson()
val geoJsonString = gson.toJson(basketA)
```

All is fine if there is only 1 basket or 1 row in the JSON file, but how about basket B, C, and D? How to insert a new line in the JSON file?

Comment: The file you're showing here is not valid JSON, but it is in fact a different format, known as [NDJSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_streaming#Line-delimited_JSON).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in one of the answer, the json that you're expecting is not properly formatted. To create the desired and correct JSON structure with multiple baskets, you can create a `Map` for each basket and then combine them into a single `Map`. Something like:

```kotlin
fun main() {
  val basketA =
      mapOf(
          "Basket A" to
              mapOf("Row 1" to "Apple", "Row 2" to "Orange", "Row 3" to "Pear", "Row 4" to "Grapes")
      )

  // Similarly for other baskets...

  val allBaskets = listOf(basketA, basketB, basketC, basketD)

  val gson = Gson()
  val jsonString = gson.toJson(allBaskets)
  val outputFile = File("output.json")
  outputFile.writeText(jsonString)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid json

```
   {"Basket A": {"Row 1":"Apple", "Row 2":"Orange", "Row 3":"Pear", "Row 4":"Grapes"}}
   {"Basket B": {"Row 1":"Mango", "Row 2":"Pineapple", "Row 3":"Kiwi", "Row 4":"Cherry"}}
   {"Basket C": {"Row 1":"Banana", "Row 2":"Papaya", "Row 3":"Watermelon", "Row 4":"Strawberry"}}
   {"Basket D": {"Row 1":"Avocado", "Row 2":"Peach", "Row 3":"Lemon", "Row 4":"Guava"}}
```

If you want to include these objects as they are in a json object you would need to be in an array like so

```
{
  "baskets": [
    {
      "Basket A": {
        "Row 1": "Apple",
        "Row 2": "Orange",
        "Row 3": "Pear",
        "Row 4": "Grapes"
      }
    },
    {
      "Basket B": {
        "Row 1": "Mango",
        "Row 2": "Pineapple",
        "Row 3": "Kiwi",
        "Row 4": "Cherry"
      }
    },
    {
      "Basket C": {
        "Row 1": "Banana",
        "Row 2": "Papaya",
        "Row 3": "Watermelon",
        "Row 4": "Strawberry"
      }
    },
    {
      "Basket D": {
        "Row 1": "Avocado",
        "Row 2": "Peach",
        "Row 3": "Lemon",
        "Row 4": "Guava"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The important things to note here are that the individual rows are comma separated inside a pair of square braces `[]` with a `baskets` key and everything is wrapped inside an outer pair of braces `{}` .

It shouldn't be too hard to adjust your code to produce the above result